# Japid configuration?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x, japid

I'm using play-1.2.5, when I execute `play japid:gen` command it show we following error.

```
~ Oops. conf/routes or conf/application.conf missing.
~ /home/ifkaar/Downloads/play-1.2.5 does not seem to host a valid application.
```

Dont know why, every thing seems to be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run `play japid:gen` under a play application, not play framework itself.

Try the followings:

1. cd to any dir you want to host your play app
2. run `play new myApp`
3. cd myApp
4. edit `conf/dependencies.yml` in the app project folder and add japid into the file
5. run `play japid:gen`

I suggest you read through the play documentation to get some basic understanding

Comment: Thanks green :). It was dependencies problem, I was not add dependencies.